# Connect from Azure Databricks Standard Tier to an Azure SQL Database on Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, databricks-sql

We are trying to connect from Azure Databricks to an Azure SQL Database on Private Endpoint. This works when the SQL DB has Public Endpoint enabled.

We have some success connecting from ADF via Databricks using Managed Integration Runtime but directly connecting from Databricks using Python Code via JDBC tends to fail with an error below. I went thru various documentation but tend to go back to start.

Please help :)

*com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access). To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database). ClientConnectionId:371496b0-8ac1-4808-9868-ff5cc7dc2914*

Comment: Do you have the SQL private end point inside the Vnet ? If yes, you can create a managed service endpoint in ADF and establish the connection to Azure SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the Private DNS zone entry in the virtual network links.
I reproduced the same error with the missing Private DNS zone entry. Once create this missing link, the issue got resolved.

[image: Private DNS zone entry]

Please see the below blog and video explained about the error.

https://www.techbrothersit.com/2021/09/connection-was-denied-since-deny-public.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNNSA4mI6AA&ab_channel=TechBrothersIT